# How can calculate the value of variable at the first time on onClickListener event?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have an operation in which the value of a variable changes during the following process. The following code shows this operation.

```
private long checkOffCode(String pChode) {
    final long[] percent = {0};
    APIGettingPosts apiGettingPosts = new APIGettingPosts(MainActivity.this, "get_off_code.php");
    apiGettingPosts.getOffCode(new APIGettingPosts.OnOffCodeReceived() {
        @Override
        public void onReceived(List<Posts> posts) {
            if (posts == null || posts.isEmpty()) {
                // There is no value on sever...
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); ++i) {

                    // If the code in serve is equal with pCode],
                    // change the price value....

                    if (pChode.equals(posts.get(i).getCode())) {
                        percent[0] = Long.valueOf(posts.get(i).getPercent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return percent[0];
}
```

The `checkOffCode` function receives a code, and returns a variable named `percent` if its value is equal to the value stored in the server.

In the event `setOnClickListener` of the `btnPurchase` button, this value is called, and using of its value, the `price` variable is computed.
The code for this section is as follows:

```
btnPurchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    long percent = 0;
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){

    percent = checkOffCode("MYCODE");
    if (percent != 0) {
        // update price value...
        price = price - price * percent / 100;
        Log.e("Success >>", String.valueOf(price));
    } else {
        Log.e("Failure >>", String.valueOf(price));
    }
}
});
```

The problem is that when I click on the `btnPurchase` button for the first time, the previous value of `percent` [percent = 0] is calculated in the operation, but when I click on the button for the second time, the variable `price` is calculated with the new `percent` value.

The output `Log cat`  is shown in both first and second clicks respectively as follow:

> > 08-28 00:45:04.589 28467-28467/? E/Success >>: 125000
> >
> > 08-28 00:45:11.425 28467-28467/? E/Success >>: 16000

**The question is:** How can I calculate the value of `price` with the new `percent` value at the first time?

Comment: what is ciOff? before leaving the checkOffCode method, restart the variable ciOff.setCode(0);

Comment: The ciOff  is the value of editText.getText(), which is sent to checkOffCode function..

Comment: should put the percent statement inside @override public void onClick (View view){
    long percent = checkOffCode("MYCODE");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation with whether you click the button first or second time.
The problem is that you try to get the return value from `checkOffCode` directly without being sure about that `onReceived` has been called. You can change the code like this:

```
private void checkOffCode(String pChode) {
    final long[] percent = {0};
    APIGettingPosts apiGettingPosts = new APIGettingPosts(MainActivity.this, "get_off_code.php");
    apiGettingPosts.getOffCode(new APIGettingPosts.OnOffCodeReceived() {
        @Override
        public void onReceived(List<Posts> posts) {
            if (posts == null || posts.isEmpty()) {
                // There is no value on sever...
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); ++i) {

                    // If the code in serve is equal with pCode],
                    // change the price value....

                    if (pChode.equals(posts.get(i).getCode())) {
                        percent[0] = Long.valueOf(posts.get(i).getPercent());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (percent[0] != 0) {
                // update price value...
                price = price - price * percent[0] / 100;
                Log.e("Success >>", String.valueOf(price));
            } else {
                Log.e("Failure >>", String.valueOf(price));
            }
        }
    });
}

btnPurchase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        checkOffCode("MYCODE");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding boolean that if firstClicked, calculate the price, so if you tap again for the second time, the calculation will not triggered. This is the example:

First make boolean variable outside the onClick function:

```
private Boolean isFirstClicked = false;
```

Then modify your onClick function:

```
if (!isFirstClicked) {
    // update price value...
    isFirstClicked = true
    price = price - price * percent / 100;
    Log.e("Success >>", String.valueOf(price));
} else {
    Log.e("Failure >>", String.valueOf(price));
}
```

Comment: I think I must used from AsyncTask, beacause i must wait for new value of _percent_ and other threads must be block, but i dont know **HOW** ?

Comment: You can check and try @orzangleli's answer.